# Разделение таблиц на части по столбцам в цикле

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for, обработка-данных

Eсть ряд таблиц с данными. Для каждой таблицы мне необходимо провести разделение на две таблицы в зависимости от названия столбцов. На данный момент я сделал следующие шаги:

1. Создал контнейнер из существующих таблиц `list_m`, которые нужно разделить

```
list_m = [other_inc_cons_cumsum_m, pr_cons_cumsum_m, ndfl_cons_cumsum_m, excise_cons_cumsum_m, property_cons_cumsum_m, ndpi_cumsum_m]
```

2. Создал два контейнера из пустых фреймов данных, в которые собираюсь записать разделенные столбцы

```
list_m_rel = [other_inc_cons_cumsum_m_rel, pr_cons_cumsum_m_rel, ndfl_cons_cumsum_m_rel, excise_cons_cumsum_m_rel, property_cons_cumsum_m_rel, ndpi_cumsum_m_rel]  
  
list_m_diff = [other_inc_cons_cumsum_m_diff, pr_cons_cumsum_m_diff, ndfl_cons_cumsum_m_diff, excise_cons_cumsum_m_diff, property_cons_cumsum_m_diff, ndpi_cumsum_m_diff]
```

3. Далее, если в названии столбца таблицы из `list_m` есть `_rel`, то этот столбец идет в таблицу из контейнера `list_m_rel`.

```
    for table_t, table_rel in zip(set_m, set_m_rel):
       l = [column for column in table_t.columns if re.findall('_rel', column) == ['_rel']]
       table_rel = table_t[l].copy()
       table_t.drop(columns = l, inplace = True)
```

4. Далее если в названии столбца таблицы из `list_m` есть `_diff`, то этот столбец идет в таблицу из контейнера `list_m_diff`.

```
    for table_t, table_diff in zip(set_m, set_m_diff):
      l = [column for column in table_t.columns if re.findall('_diff', column) == ['_diff']]
      table_diff = table_t[l]
      table_t.drop(columns = l, inplace = True)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что по итогу таблицы из `list_m` лишаются столбцов с `_diff` и `_rel`, а таблицы из `list_m_diff` и `list_m_rel` остаются пустыми.

Comment: а зачем вы делаете дропы тогда? и вообще, какой-то странный подход к решению.

Comment: Буду благодарен любому другому подходу.
Просто в первоначальных таблицах остаются еще столбцы кроме тех, что содержат _rel и _diff
Мне нужно, чтобы в итоге было три таблицы с тем содержим, которое мне необходимо, одна получается, а две другие пустые

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Из комментариев:

> Но мне необходимо, чтобы таблица df1 распалась на две отдельные
> таблицы, а таблица df2 распалась на две другие таблицы

Не уверен, что вы действительно хотите множить в памяти одни и те же данные в различном виде. Зачем разделять и сохранять каждый фрейм на два если это легко делается "на лету":

Пример:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"a_rel":[1,2,3], "a_diff":[11,12,13]})
b = pd.DataFrame({"b_rel":[21,22,23], "b_diff":[41,42,43]})
c = pd.DataFrame({"c_rel":[31,32,33], "c_diff":[51,52,53]})
```

если нам нужны все "_rel" столбцы:

```
In [16]: pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1).filter(regex="_rel$")
Out[16]: 
   a_rel  b_rel  c_rel
0      1     21     31
1      2     22     32
2      3     23     33

In [17]: pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1).filter(regex="_diff$")
Out[17]: 
   a_diff  b_diff  c_diff
0      11      41      51
1      12      42      52
2      13      43      53
```

разумеется тоже самое можно делать с каждым отдельным фреймом:

```
In [18]: a.filter(regex="_rel$")
Out[18]: 
   a_rel
0      1
1      2
2      3
```

Comment: Понимаете, вы фильтруете стобцы входящих таблиц и укладываете их либо в ящик А либо в ящик Б. Но мне нужен был несколько иной функционал. Мне необходимо было *для каждой* входящей таблицы создавать *две новые* таблицы, которые состоят из столбцов предыдущей по условию. Понимаю, задача специфическая, но так было нужно. Свою реализацию я указал отдельным решением.

Comment: @АлександрГордеев, жаль, что вы не поняли моего решения и не увидели его потенциал - нет необходимости создавать две дополнительные таблицы из одной для того, чтобы выгрузить их в Excel - это легко делается на лету

Comment: Тэкс, тут вы научили меня эффективно фильтровать столбцы таблицы.
Я это делал так:

`
      l = [column for column in table_t.columns if re.findall('_diff', column) == ['_diff']]
`

Очень некрасиво, но это работало, вопрос был в другом.
Если уж пойти дальше, то да, мне нужно было взять кучу имеющихся таблиц, в которых хранится разная информация. Посчитать для каждого столбца этих таблиц относительные и абсолютные разницы. А потом выгрузить для каждой таблицы  отдельно столбцы с изначальными данными, отдельно столбцы с абсолютными разницами и столбцы относительными разницами.

Comment: “Для каждой таблицы мне необходимо провести разделение на две таблицы в зависимости от названия столбцов.” т.е. вопрос все-таки не в этом?? Я думаю если бы вы нормально описали вопрос и __привели воспроизводимые примеры входных и выходных данных__, то ответы бы получили гораздо более полезные ;)

Answer (score 2):

я бы предложил сделать так:

исходные данные:

```
import pandas as pd

# исходные фреймы
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"abcd":[1,2,3], "fgkl":[11,12,13]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"cd_ab":[21,22,23], "5_kl":[41,42,43]})

# результирующие фреймы:

ab = pd.DataFrame()
kl = pd.DataFrame()
```

и само решение:

```
for df in [df1, df2]: # берем каждый датафрейм из списка
    for x in list(df.columns): # берем название каждого столбца датафрейма
        if "ab" in x:
            ab = pd.concat([ab, df[x]], axis=1)
        if "kl" in x:
            kl = pd.concat([kl, df[x]], axis=1)
```

тогда и исходные фреймы остаются в целости и результирующие получают то, что вам нужно:

```
#ab:
   abcd  cd_ab
0     1     21
1     2     22
2     3     23
       
#kl:
   fgkl  5_kl
0    11    41
1    12    42
2    13    43
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, тут столбцы таблиц из списка [df1, df2] распределяются по таблицам ab и kl.
Но мне необходимо, чтобы таблица df1 распалась на две отдельные таблицы, а таблица df2 распалась на две другие таблицы

Comment: @АлександрГордеев, я понял вопрос точно также как strawdog. Можете привести в вопросе примеры трех небольших фреймов (в виде Python кода как в этом ответе) и результат, который вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая реализация:

```
set_m = [other_inc_cons_cumsum_m, pr_cons_cumsum_m, ndfl_cons_cumsum_m, excise_cons_cumsum_m, property_cons_cumsum_m, ndpi_cons_cumsum_m]

for table in set_m:
  for column in table.columns:
    table[column + ' _rel'] = (table[column] - table[column].shift(12)) / table[column].shift(12)
    table[column + ' _diff'] = (table[column]) - table[column].shift(12)

map_rel = {}
map_diff = {}
names = ["other_inc_cons", "pr_cons", "ndfl_cons", "excise_cons", "property_cons", "ndpi_cons"]

for table_t, name in zip(set_m, names):
  l = [column for column in table_t.columns if re.findall('_rel', column) == ['_rel']]
  map_rel[name+'_cumsum_m_rel'] = table_t[l]
  table_t.drop(columns = l, inplace = True)

for table_t, name in zip(set_m, names):
  l = [column for column in table_t.columns if re.findall('_diff', column) == ['_diff']]
  map_diff[name+'_cumsum_m_diff'] = table_t[l]
  table_t.drop(columns = l, inplace = True)
```

Потом каждая таблица из map-ов выгружается в эксель.

Comment: столько циклов - ужОс! :-D